# php form submission-checking not being recognized

Tags: php, forms, submission

I basically took in 3 pieces of data from a form, and before processing them, I just wanted to make sure that all fields were filled in.  So the focus of this is the second to last IF statement, checking if the different variables are empty.  It seems to only be working for the first variable and I can't figure out how to make it apply to all of them.

```
<?php



include ("account.php") ;
include ("connect.php") ;


$isdone = FALSE;
$un  =  $_REQUEST [ "un"] ; 
$pw   =  $_REQUEST [ "pw"] ;



$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `auth` WHERE username = '$un'") or die(mysql_error());

$info = mysql_fetch_array($data);

$info['username']; 
$password = $info['pw'];

session_start();


if(trim($un) != '' && trim($pw) != '' && $password == $pw)
{

    $_SESSION['uze']=$un;


    include "problem.html";

}


elseif( !isset($_POST['submit1']) && $isdone == FALSE)
{
    echo "wrong password";
}



$selected =  $_REQUEST [ "type"] ; 


if($selected == 'afs')
{
    $typeinc = 'afs';
}
else if($selected == 'db')
{
    $typeinc = 'database';
}
else if($selected == 'cs')
{
    $typeinc = 'computer systems';
}
else if($selected == 'pw')
{
    $typeinc = 'password';
} 
else if($selected == 'hw')
{
    $typeinc = 'hardware';
}
else if($selected == 'other')
{
    $typeinc = 'other';
}

$text = $_REQUEST ["inc"];

$selected2 = $_REQUEST ["yesno"];

if($selected2 == 'yes')
{
    $email = 'yes';
}
else
{
    $email = 'no';
}



if(isset($_POST['submit1']))
{
    if(empty($typeinc) || empty($text) || empty($email))
    {
        print( '<a href="http://web.njit.edu/~swp5/assignment/auth.html">You have not filled in all fields, click to sign in and re-enter</a>' );
    }

}


else{
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `swp5_proj`. `inci` (`type`, `date`, `time`, `reporter`, `desc`) VALUES ('$typeinc', CURDATE(), CURTIME(), '".$_SESSION['uze']."', '$text');") or die(mysql_error());

    mysql_query("DELETE FROM inci WHERE type = ' '");
$isdone = TRUE;

}

if(isset($_POST['submit1']) && $isdone == TRUE)
{
    echo "session over";
}



?>
```

Comment: Why hello, little [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com), won't you come in and play?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you clean your REQUEST variables before you put them in a MySQL query.

Answer (score 0):

`if((trim($un) !== '') && (trim($pw) !== '') && ($password == $pw))`

Comment: I'm referring to the IF statement checking:   if(isset($_POST['submit1']))

Answer (score 0):

You're setting $email to yes or no in the line just above.

Answer (score 0):

In your if statement you are using the shortcut OR operator.... As soon as a single statement evaluates to true, the entire statement evaluates to true and there is no need to continue processing further.

Comment: Yes, I want it to cover all variations of possibility.  IE, if they have only one selected, none, or 2.  Does that make sense?